# Bad access while parsing with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsxmlparser, exc-bad-access

I use following code for parsing:

```
    //init parser with readStr  
    NSData* xmlData = [stringToParse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSXMLParser* xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];

    //parse with events
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];//<<<< BAD ACCESS!! 

    //release parser
    [xmlParser release];
```

I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" at the line [xmlParser parse];. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you'll need to post more of your code, and perhaps the full backtrace for the crash, and any console output if there is any. Also check that xmlData is not null (eg. add assert(xmlData) between the 2nd and 3rd liens.

Comment: nothing seems to be nil , I checked. I think it is a synchronization issue =/. I'll post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok with this code. It seems the problem was elsewhere. Sorry for that.